# Is there a way to check the bottom of a child div?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to implement an Infinity scroll.

But not a window object, the target is a child div with a scroller.

Is there a way to examine the current height of a child div with JavaScript?

For example, I would like to request an event when the scroll touches at the end.

This is my template code.

```
<div
          style="overflow-y: scroll; height:500px;"
          class="scroll-content"
          @scroll="onScroll"
>
```

Comment: normallly it's as simple as calling `xxx.addEventListener('scroll', myFunc);` on the element you want to get scroll events on

Comment: @ControlAltDel Thank you for your answer.
When used in regular window objects, the event parameters were used to compare the height of the window to check if it was the last.
But in cases like subdiv, I didn't know which factor to use, so I left a question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```js
var listElm = document.querySelector('#infinite-list');

// Add items.
var nextItem = 1;
var loadMore = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var item = document.createElement('li');
    item.innerText = 'Item ' + nextItem++;
    listElm.appendChild(item);
  }
}

// Detect when scrolled to bottom.
listElm.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  if (listElm.scrollTop + listElm.clientHeight >= listElm.scrollHeight) {
    loadMore();
  }
});

// Initially load some items.
loadMore();
```

```css
#infinite-list {
  /* We need to limit the height and show a scrollbar */
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;

  /* Optional, only to check that it works with margin/padding */
  margin: 30px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 10px solid black;
}

/* Optional eye candy below: */
li {
  padding: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<ul id='infinite-list'>
</ul>
```

Comment: I found the client height to be too small sometimes

Answer (score 1):

The following function returns, whether the user has scrolled to the bottom of a certain element:

```
function scrollEnd(el) {
    return (el.scrollTop + el.offsetHeight >= el.scrollHeight);
}
```

If you add this to a scroll event listener:

```
element.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    if (scrollEnd(element)) {
        // the user reached the end
    }
})
```

I tried this on a textarea, should work with anything, though.